# How to alter file upload description text

Tags: 8, theming, files

I'm trying to customize text for a file upload widget in Drupal 8.

Here is a screenshot of the widget:

[image: File upload widget]

I just want to display the first `15 MB` which I added as file field description text in the content type.

The trouble is the last 3 lines of text have no HTML tags so I can't selectively hide it with `display:none;`. Here is what I mean:

[image: HTML for file upload]

I tried this CSS but it doesn't work:

```
#edit-field-dataset-file-0--description * {
    display:none;
}

#edit-field-dataset-file-0--description p {
    display:inline !important;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There's a chance that a form alter might help in this case but I am not sure, I'll see if I have some time to test it out.

Comment: Yeah, try to hook into the form using hook_form_alter and unset the description.

Comment: Thanks @DannyEnglander @leymannx! I used `hook_field_widget_form_alter`. Feel free to post your own code which I can accept as an answer but in the meantime I'm going to post a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used `hook_field_widget_form_alter` as suggested by DannyEnglander and leymannx.

[8.8.x hook_field_widget_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/8.8.x)

Replace `MYMODULE` with your custom module's name and alter the element array to suit your needs.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  if (get_class($context['widget']) === 'Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\FileWidget' && !empty($context['form']['#attributes'])) {
    $element['#description'] = '<p>File must be less than <strong>15 MB</strong>.<br/>Allowed types: <code>txt csv tsv xls xlsx sav sas7bdat</code></p>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've got it! I think you can accept this as the answer.

Comment: SE says I can accept the answer in two days. I hope I don't forget.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a preprocess function like this:

```
function theme_preprocess_file_upload_help(array &$variables) {
  $description = $variables['descriptions']; // It's where the three objects are, you can manipulate the description.
}
```

Or if you want just to add some wrappers around each element, modify the template `file-upload-help.html.twig`.
Currently it looks like this:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display help text for file fields.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - descriptions: Lines of help text for uploading a file.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_file_upload_help()
 */
#}
{{ descriptions|safe_join('<br />') }}
```

Instead you can do:

```
{% for item in descriptions %}
  <div class="help-text-item">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If altering the file field widget description in hook_field_widget_form_alter() doesn't work.

You can try to add a process function to change the description like it is mentioned by gnuget in this [Drupal issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2815537) :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function HOOK_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $context) {
  if (isset($element['#field_name']) && $element['#field_name'] == 'field_media_image') {
      // Add process callback to change field description.
      $element['#process'][] = '_change_description';
    }
  }
}

/**
 *  The description field is build in a #process callback so we need to add another callback.
 */
function _change_description($element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form) {
  $element['#description'] = t('Your new description');
  return $element;
}
```